# How to append first and last element in each vector (of a different length) of a list in R, without making the code slow?

Tags: r, list, append, spike

I am working on simulating nonhomogeneous processes to understand the neural behavior better. My code works in a way that I have, say `20` trials lasting `2` seconds each (each trial representing a spike train). Then the list `SpikeTimes` gives me a list of `20` vectors where each vector corresponds to the time stamps of where the spikes occurred in that particular trial. [Eg.`SpikeTimes[1]` which looks like this, `0.002250802 0.053934034...1.971574170 2.023090384` means that in the first Spike Train, spikes occurred at `0.002250802`, `0.053934034` and so on. I don't know why it also brings up a time stamps beyond my time limit of `2` seconds, but I will work on that later]. My code looks like this--

```
nTrials=20
t_max=2.0000000


LambdaInv<- function(x){ifelse( x< 15, x/30,
                    ifelse(x >= 15 & x < 38, ((x-15)/46)+0.5,
                           ifelse(x >= 38 & x <53, ((x-38)/30)+1.0,
                                  ifelse(x >= 53 & x< 67.4, ((x-53)/72)+1.5, 
                                         ((x-67.4)/30)+1.7))))}
   
 t = 0 
 s = 0
 X = numeric(0)


 NonHomoSpikes <- function(t_max){
  while(t <= t_max){
    u <- runif(1)
    s <- s-log(u)
    t <- LambdaInv(s)
    X <- c(X,t)
       }
    return(X)
   }


SpikeTimes <- lapply(1:nTrials, function(x) NonHomoSpikes(2))
```

My problem is that, for each of the vector in the list `SpikeTimes`; which gives time stamps of spikes, I also want to include the beginning (that is `0`) and the end (that is `2`) of the spike train. So I want to append this list to have each vector include the first entry as `0` and the last entry as `2`.

My `SpikeTimes[1]` would then look like `0 0.002250802 0.053934034...1.971574170 2` and other `SpikeTimes[i]` would look similar. I tried `SpikeTimes <- c(0, SpikeTimes)` for entering `0` in the beginning but it only made the list have 21 vectors instead of 20 with the vector `0` as the first element (I mean I get why that happened). How can I do it in a way that doesn't make my code slow? I am newbie in R and reading up on the internet hasn't help with this particular problem. I would appreciate any sort of input.

Comment: just change `NonHomoSpikes` `return` statement to `return(c(0, X, 2))`

Comment: @pieca thank you that worked! I can't believe it was that simple. Would you also have some advice on how to stop my`SpikeTimes` at `2`? Right now, as shown in the example it's also including some time instances between `2.0` and `2.1` as the last entries. If you could offer some advice on that, it would really help me.

Comment: well, this has to do with your model, but if you want to 'manually' stop if t>2, then insert `if(t > 2) break` after line `t <- LambdaInv(s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: change `NonHomoSpikes` `return` statement to `return(c(0, X, 2))`.

To 'manually' stop `if t < 2` (as described in comments):

```
NonHomoSpikes <- function(t_max){
  while(t <= t_max){
    u <- runif(1)
    s <- s-log(u)
    t <- LambdaInv(s)
    if(t > 2) break
    X <- c(X,t)
       }
    return(c(0,X,0))
   }
```